# Como posso utilizar um teclado virtual em uma aplicação Kivy ou KivyMD?

Tags: python-3.x, python-kivy, kivy

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em python com interface gráfica feita em KivyMD. Minha dúvida é a seguinte, quando eu clicar em algum campo `textinput` quero que apareça um teclado virtual para poder inserir os dados. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Eu sei [fazer no Kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.vkeyboard.html). Veja se a documentação o ajuda pois com o material design eu não sei se funciona pois há diferença entre Kivy e KivyMD.

Comment: Eu vi alguns exemplos do Kivy, porém não entendi muito bem como chamo dentro de um `.kv` o teclado

Comment: Ainda não descobri como utilizar isso, eu consegui fazer o teclado funcionar, mas não junto com as telas que criei.

Comment: Então eu estou igual a você. Antes de comentar eu havia feito um exemplo com as bibliotecas padrão Kivy e funcionou mas quando testei usando Material Design não funcionou. Agora eu dei uma pesquisada e parece que há mais de um projeto KivMD: https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD e https://pypi.org/project/kivymd/ . Um é o original, que parece ter sido descontinuado e o outro é fork do primeiro.

Comment: Pois é, cheguei ao mesmo ponto, acredito que terei que procurar um meio termo, antes estou tentando colocar o vkeyboard dentro de um popup, já estou ficando sem ideias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma configuração que funcionou utilizando o KivyMD:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')
```

Adicionei apenas isso e funcionou normalmente. Também deve funcionar para o Kivy.